# Least square method, why gradient gives the minimum and not the maximum?

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, least-squares

I'm bit confused about finding critical points of functions.

Studying the least square method we got some data $\{(y_{1},x_{1}),...,(y_{n},x_{n}))\}$ and can define error associating with $y=ax+b$ by

$$E(a,b)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-[ax_{i}+b])^{2}$$

We want to find the minimum of $E$ and so we find where its gradient is equal to zero. i.e.

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial a}=0=\frac{\partial E}{\partial b}$$

but, by doing that we would fint just a critical point, it could be a minimum or maximum or neither of them.

But anyway this calculus give me the exactly minimum points, my doubt is why that? do we have the second derivative criterion here?

Comment: One answer is to recognize that the objective function is convex, and to invoke the fact that for a convex function any point where the gradient is $0$ is guaranteed to be a global minimizer.

Comment: @littleO, is there some general properties like this to quadratic functions in general?

Comment: Here's another viewpoint. The objective function, expressed in vector notation, is $E(\beta) = \frac12 \| X \beta - y \|^2$. The gradient of $E$ is $\nabla E(\beta) = X^T(X \beta - y)$, and the Hessian of $E$ is $\nabla^2 E(\beta) = X^T X$. If $X$ has linearly independent columns, then $X^T X$ is guaranteed to be positive definite, so the second derivative test implies that any point $\beta$ which satisfies $\nabla E(\beta) = 0$ must be a local minimizer.

Comment: @littleO, the columns are $[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ and $[1,...,1]$. The conditions for they be LD is not very unusual?